# calling a json web service every second

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-7

i'd created a `json web service` & used in my web site.
Now i want use it in my windows phone app to show the data, which is receiving by that web service. So that i'v written the code below--->

```
     //// some code

StartThread();
        }

            void StartThread()
            {
                DispatcherTimer TradeThread = new DispatcherTimer();
                TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                TradeThread.Tick += new EventHandler(BindData);
                TradeThread.Start();
            }

            void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some URL"));
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            }

            void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
                ///// some code
```

The code is working fine, but i think the web client, i'v written in `BindData` method is instantiated on every time (every 100ms), & it might be the reason that my running quite slow......

**is there any way to instantiate it(web client) once & updating the downloaded string on every call ???**
So if anyone have used the web services than plz check my code above & do comment or edit it if any of the error there

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling it every second. You are calling it every 1/10th of a second which is a hell of a short time. If you wanted to call it every second make sure you specify the correct interval:

```
TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
```

or if you prefer:

```
TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

The instantiation of a `WebClient` is not an expensive operation that you should be worried about.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov :: Question is corrected & i am not asking why it is slow, my matter was "Is it correct to instantiate the Web Client every time ?"

Comment: @@@Darin Dimitrov:: hey Darin, there is one more problem in this code it caching the data after some requests, so data not updating on as web requests ...... can u solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if its the best way to go about it (blindly checking every second) you might get someone with a slow or intermittent connection.
I think the DownloadStringComplete should fire even if the thread is paused, so perhaps you could make the json call, pause the thread, then unpause it in the downloadComplete event. if that doesnt work, maybe you could set an internal variable, something like _receivedData and set that to false just before sending the request, then set it back to true inside the downloadComplete.. something like...

```
        void StartThread()
        {
            DispatcherTimer TradeThread = new DispatcherTimer();
            TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            TradeThread.Tick += new EventHandler(BindData);
            TradeThread.Start();
        }

        Boolean _receivedData = true;
        void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(_receivedData)
            {
                _receivedData = false;
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some URL"));
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            }
        }

        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _receivedData = true;
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
            ///// some code
```